# Javascript download: detect rename of file

Tags: javascript

If I use some code like this, to start a Download with Javascript in my browser:

```
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.style.display = "none";
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
link.download = file.name;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Do I have any way to understand if the file has been renamed during download? I mean: if I download two times the file `test.txt`, the second one is renamed in something like `test(1).txt`.

Any chance to detect this change in the script?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to detect the name change? Seems like a weird thing to worry about.

Comment: it was just a test, to avoid multiple downloads, but it was more something I was curious about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These no way to detect the filename change.

if u want avoid the duplicated download (file name duplicated) from the same page as alternative solution u can create on an array to store previous filename

Answer (score 3):

No.

There is no API that would provide that information.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming gets done by the browser automatically if there already is a file with the same name. Therefore no.

Comment: I realized that it might be possible, in case you are using a Chrome Extension, or a Browser Extension per se. I found this documentation that might enable this behaviour in Chrome. Haven‘t tested it yet though: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/